# how access schedular function in linux module kernel?

Tags: module, kernel

I wanna write a linux mudule kernel that count the number of invoking schedular
I dont have any idea how I can access schedular function or any other idea for counting that
any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

finally i found we should find the addreess of scheduler() in system.map then count the  number of reading that part of memory  but how i can get prmission to access system.map and how i can count the number of reading special part of memory